# How to avoid manual framework switching for device and simulator in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, git, version-control

I am using a third party framework in my iOS code. The framework is different for running in device and simulator. Now I need to manually change the framework everytime when I switch from simulator to device and back.

Is there any way to handle this using xCode or git ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can combine the x86 and ARM frameworks into a single framework if you want using `lipo`

Comment: This frame work coming from a third party company. They provide it separately

Comment: What's involved with manually changing the framework?